# Google Music - Update metadata for multiple files?

Tags: google-play-music

Apparently, a significant number of files that I've uploaded have incorrect metadata.

Is there any way to (via the web interface) update this metadata in groups, rather than one file at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click (on Windows) or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + click (on Mac OS X) to select multiple files, then click on the menu triangle next to any song title and select **Edit song info (x)**. (x) is the number of files you have selected.

[image: Edit multiple files]

You can also click the first song in a list, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click the last song in a list to select both songs and all songs in between.